# Spock testing SpringSecurity methods

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spring-security, spock

I'm trying to test the LoginController of SpringSecurity (using the spring-test version 3.1.0.RELEASE) using Spock in Grails. Specifically I'm trying to do the unit test for the following method:

```
    def index() {
        if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
            redirect uri: SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl
        }
        else {
            redirect action: 'auth', params: params
        }
    }
```

I've tried using the following test:

```
    void "Calling index"(){
        given:
        controller.springSecurityService = Mock(SpringSecurityService)
        when:
        controller.index()
        then:
        1 * controller.springSecurityService.isLoggedIn() >> false
        response.redirectedUrl == '/login/auth'
        when:
        controller.response.reset()
        controller.index()
        then:
        1 * controller.springSecurityService.isLoggedIn() >> true
        response.redirectedUrl == '/login'
    }
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DefaultSecurityConfig`

Does anyone know why it happens and how it's solved?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I do not use Spring or Grails, but if a class is not found, chances are that you a dependency is missing on the class path. Maybe your Gradle or Maven build configuration needs some fixing.

Comment: I think I have everything, because the login in a normal run does not show that error, that is, I think the spring-security version should be fine); and I also have among my dependencies the spring-test.

Comment: What you think and what I can verify is not the same. Without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) all of this is pure speculation.